# How to assign letters in the rows of a matrix in C

Tags: c

I'm starting to learn C and while I was programming I had a doubt, how do you assign a vector like this:letters[8]= {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'} to the rows of a matrix and a vector like this: numbers[5]={1,2,3,4,5} to the columns of the same matrix so that the matrix looks like this:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
==============
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
==============
etc.
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're talking about. Do you want to output a matrix in the described way?

Comment: Sounds like your matrix would be a 2D array of char arrays; which makes it a 3D char array. Not sure if you want that if you're just starting out. So, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I want to program a matrix like the one that i used for example

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do. But if it is just the output you want then here's a hint: `printf("%c%d ", 'A', 1);`. Apply that to your situation using a loop.

Comment: Thank you for the info guys

Comment: If you post some code we can help you figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Look up for loops. Try looping over the contents of just one vector and do something with each item.

Now try nesting two for loops, one for each vector. Try output in the inner loop and see what you get.

How can you use these tools to get your desired result?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  But the answer is only seven lines of code + four lines of variable declarations so it would be silly to write it all for him...

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was never updated with an attempt at some code I am assuming that wadin doesn't need the answer anymore, but it is a Q&A site so someone may benefit from having this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    /* declare some variables for loop indexes */
    int row,column;

    /* declare some variables for the row values */
    char letters[]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'};
    int rows=sizeof(letters)/sizeof(char);

    /* declare some variables for the column values */
    int numbers[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int columns=sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int);

    /* declare some variables for the matrix */
    char matrix[rows][columns][sizeof("H5")]; /* H5 is the biggest one...*/

    /* actually make the matrix */
    for(row=0;row<rows;row++)
      for(column=0;column<columns;column++)
        sprintf(matrix[row][column],"%c%d",letters[row],numbers[column]);

    /* display the matrix */
    for(row=0;row<rows;row++)
    {
      for(column=0;column<columns;column++)
        printf("%s ",matrix[row][column]);
      puts("\n==============");
    }

    return 0;
}
```